# IntelliJ doesn't want to import

Tags: python, intellij-idea

The problem is that IntelliJ Studio 13 doesn't want to recognize an import. I have my code like this

a folder named "app". Inside it

**__init__.py**

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

from app import views, models
```

**views.py**

```
from flask import render_template, request
from models import *
from app import *

@app.route('/')
@app.route('/index')
def index(): 
    return "123"
```

Now in views.py the "from app import *" is greyed as unused, and there's a red warning under @app with "unresolved reference "app".

Can anyone explain me why is this happening and what's the fix for this. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since you're importing everything from models and app, why not just use `import models, app`?

Comment: Sometimes I meet the same problem, I don't know why, But I usually restart the IDE or wait for IDE finishing resolving the package.

Comment: @RevanProdigalKnight if I write import app it works. Thanks. if you want make it an answer.

Comment: @Unlucky doesn't work by restarting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`from app import *` will import the package contents into the current namespace.  So the *route* function from the *app* package will be imported into the current namespace.  Callable as `route()`.

`import app` will import the *app* package into the current namespace as an object named *app*.  Callable as `app.route()`

Generally the use of `from app import *` is frowned upon unless you are certain it is what you want to do.  `from app import route` would be preferred.

Comment: You are correct. but @RevanProdigalKnight beat you with 8 minutes :D

Comment: @OWADVL Oh, just accept Isaac's answer. I don't mind not getting the points.